# Compare a text file with a pattern of text in c#?

Tags: c#

I have compared a text file with a pattern like `".."`   It is writing the whole line in to the log like this...

```
insert into depdb..fin_quick_code_met
```

But i need to write this alone
 `depdb` 
   or 
 `depdb..fin_quick_code_met`

i.e) i need the word alone

```
if (line.contains(".."))
dest.WriteLine("LineNo : " + counter.ToString() + " : " +"           "+ line.TrimStart());
```

How to write this word alone?
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
        string line = "insert into depdb..fin_quick_code_met";
        foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(line, @"(\w*)\.\.")) {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
        }
```

or for just a single (the first) match on the line:

```
        Match match = Regex.Match(line, @"(\w*)\.\.");
        if (match.Success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
        }
```

To get the full `depdb..fin_quick_code_met`; the same code, but with `@"\w*\.\.\w*`, looking at `match.Value`.

Comment: @Marc Gravell:ok Marc if i need this depdb..fin_quick_code_met what should i give instead of @"(\w*)\.\."?

Comment: @bala3569 `\w*\.\.\w*` and check the `match.Value`

Comment: @Marc Gravell:i have 2k lines...i have to get it distinctly

Comment: @bala3569 then loop over them, adding each found chunk to a `HashSet<string>`. When done, loop over the hash-set.

Comment: @Marc Gravell:i have to write a word with double dot only...but it is writing like depdb...(tripledot) i.e) the match case is (depdb..)

Comment: @bala3569 you can tweak the \w to something more specific; [a-zA-Z] maybe

Answer (score 1):

If your line contains only one **..** entry, then this will work

```
  var line= "insert into depdb..fin_quick_code_met";           
  if (line.contains(".."))
   {           
        var splitted = line.Split(new[] { ".." }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var firstPart = splitted.First().Split(' ').Last();
        var secondPart = splitted.Last();
        var composed = firstPart + ".." + secondPart;
    }
```

Comment: ya thats ok, i mean it works if ".." appears only once in a single line. updated the code for more clarity...