# Compare a text file with a pattern of text in c#?

Tags: c#, file-io

I have compared a text file with a pattern like ".." and i need to write only the distinct values in a text file...

```
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(line, @"(\w*)\.\."))
    {
        dest.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
    }

    counter++;
}
```

How to get the distinct values...Any suggestion?

Comment: Now you have two problems: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add matches to a list if they've not already been added? Or just keep a running list of what's already been added? Something *like*:

```
List<string> seen = new List<string>();
    string line = string.Empty;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(line, @"(\w*)\.\."))
        {
            if (!seen.Contains(line))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
                seen.Add(line);
            }
        }
    }
```

edit: I interpreted what you were after here; if you really do want the match group value, replace line in the conditional block with match.Groups[1].Value ...

Comment: @Tim: FYI: Instead of using `<pre>`, you should rather just copy your code and click the icon for code formatting, because it's sets colour to code as well.

Comment: @Tim Barrass:System.Collection.Generic.List<string>.contains(string) has some invalid arguments

Comment: @Robert, ta (there's an icon for code formatting? will look harder! :)) and @bala3569 thanks, will correct

Comment: @Tim. Yes there is. the one with 0s and 1s... But you can format it as such yourself as well if you indent your code either using TAB or 4 SPACES. Unfortunately TABs can't be input in the editor since it moves focus (as browsers usually do). But if you copy code from VS or Notepad++ or similar, TABs will do the trick just fine.

Comment: @Tim Barrass:Dint get ur point...i just need distinct values from the matched patterns

Comment: @bala -- do you want distinct whole lines? That's what I worked up there, after guessing what your file looks like.

Comment: @Tim Barrass:no not whole line distinct particular word(matched word i.e)(match.Groups[1]))

Comment: @bala ok then, you'll need to modify the code slightly as i suggested .. good luck

Comment: @bala -- no, I've pointed the way, I'm sure you can take it from here.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend pushing your values into an array and using this to ignore duplicates:

```
ArrayList myValues = new ArrayList();

while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
  foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(line, @"(\w*)\.\."))
  {
    if(!myValues.Contains(match.Groups[1])) {
         myValues.Add(match.Groups[1]);
         dest.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]);
    }
  } 
  counter++;
}
```

Comment: myValues count is 17540 with full set of duplicates

Answer (score 0):

How about you add the match.Group[1] to a HashSet?

```
HashSet<string> hs = new HashSet<string>();
string line = "insert into depdb..fin_quick_code_met..jjj..depdb..jjj";
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(line, @"(\w*)\.\."))
{
    hs.Add(match.Groups[1].ToString());
}
foreach (string item in hs)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4457814/compare-a-text-file-with-a-pattern-of-text-in-c

Comment: FYI, HashSet<> is in System.Collections.Generic namespace and can be found in .NET 3.5 only http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495294.aspx